# How to stream audio to v20160207 Alexa Voice Service API in iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, http2, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I've been working on an iOS Alexa app for a while but i'm struggling sending the microphone audio as a stream to the AVS API.

I succeeded prerecording an audio sample and sending that as a whole and getting response.

I just want to know how I can stream data to AVS with a NSURLSession http/2 connection.

Here is a code snippet what i'm doing now:

```
func sendData() {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://avs-alexa-na.amazon.com/v20160207/events")!)
        request.setValue("Bearer \(Settings.Credentials.TOKEN)", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let boundry = NSUUID().UUIDString
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundry)"
        request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")

        let bodyData = NSMutableData()

        let jsonData = "{\"context\":[{\"header\":{\"namespace\":\"Alerts\",\"name\":\"AlertsState\"},\"payload\":{\"allAlerts\":[],\"activeAlerts\":[]}},{\"header\":{\"namespace\":\"AudioPlayer\",\"name\":\"PlaybackState\"},\"payload\":{\"token\":\"\",\"offsetInMilliseconds\":0,\"playerActivity\":\"IDLE\"}},{\"header\":{\"namespace\":\"Speaker\",\"name\":\"VolumeState\"},\"payload\":{\"volume\":25,\"muted\":false}},{\"header\":{\"namespace\":\"SpeechSynthesizer\",\"name\":\"SpeechState\"},\"payload\":{\"token\":\"\",\"offsetInMilliseconds\":0,\"playerActivity\":\"FINISHED\"}}],\"event\":{\"header\":{\"namespace\":\"SpeechRecognizer\",\"name\":\"Recognize\",\"messageId\":\"messageId-123\",\"dialogRequestId\":\"dialogRequestId-321\"},\"payload\":{\"profile\":\"CLOSE_TALK\",\"format\":\"AUDIO_L16_RATE_16000_CHANNELS_1\"}}}"

        bodyData.appendData("--\(boundry)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        bodyData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"metadata\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        bodyData.appendData("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        bodyData.appendData(jsonData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        bodyData.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        bodyData.appendData("--\(boundry)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        bodyData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        //        bodyData.appendData("Content-Type: audio/L16; rate=16000; channels=1\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        bodyData.appendData("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        bodyData.appendData(audioData!)
        bodyData.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        bodyData.appendData("--\(boundry)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60000
        session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60000

        let upload = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: bodyData) { (data, response, error) in
            print("done")
            if(data?.length > 0) {
                print("break")
            }
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if let responseData = data, let contentTypeHeader = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] {

                    var boundry: String?
                    let ctbRange = contentTypeHeader.rangeOfString("boundary=.*?;", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
                    if ctbRange.location != NSNotFound {
                        let boundryNSS = contentTypeHeader.substringWithRange(ctbRange) as NSString
                        boundry = boundryNSS.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 9, length: boundryNSS.length - 10))
                    }

                    if let b = boundry {
                        let parts = self.parseResponse(responseData, boundry: b)
                        print("got parts")
//                        self.sendSynchronize()
                        self.successHandler?(data: responseData, parts:self.parseResponse(responseData, boundry: b))
                    } else {
                        print("something went wrong")
                        self.errorHandler?(error: NSError(domain: Settings.Error.ErrorDomain, code: Settings.Error.AVSResponseBorderParseErrorCode, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Could not find boundry in AVS response"]))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        upload.resume()
    }
```

This function get's called every 320 bytes of audio data because that's the size Amazon recommends for streaming :)

Greets!

Comment: Any luck @tomwyckhuys ? Me too struck in same issue. I have also tried removing the end boundary term.

Comment: Hi check this code https://github.com/grimlockrocks/alexa-swift3-sample-app

Answer (score 0):

You should [send the JSON metadata headers only once](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/avs-http2-requests), at the beginning of the dialog request (e.g., the moment the mic is open and starts recording).

You'll also want to use the same boundary value for each time you call your sendData method for the same stream. Use the same HTTP/2 stream for the entirety of the request, which means you'll need to refactor your sendData method "inside out" to accommodate this. Examples that use uploadTask:withStreamedRequest could be helpful (which you will probably need to use).

I'm not familiar with the Swift HTTP/2 APIs, so I don't know if continuation frames will be handled for you, or if you will need to manage that yourself, so it's something to look out for. Best luck and hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```swift
public func send(event: AlexaEvent?) {
        self.queue.async {[weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let urlStr = self.host.appending(AlexaConstant.ServiceUrl.eventsURL)
            var eventRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr)!)
            eventRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            eventRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(AlexaConstant.HttpBodyData.boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            self.addAuthHeader(request: &eventRequest)
            guard let bodyData = event?.HTTPBodyData else { return }
            eventRequest.httpBody = bodyData
//            self.bodyStream = InputStream(data: bodyData)
            eventRequest.httpBodyStream = self.bodyStream

            let uploadTask = self.session?.uploadTask(withStreamedRequest: eventRequest)
            guard let task = uploadTask else { return }
            self.state = .started(.init(task: task))
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

The input and output streams are then bound in the URLSessionDataDelegate proxy method：

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, needNewBodyStream completionHandler: @escaping (InputStream?) -> Void) {
        let sendTimer = Timer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(1), target: self, selector: #selector(didFire(sendTimer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        let streamingState = StreamingState(task: task, sendTimer: sendTimer)
        self.state = .streaming(streamingState)
        var bodyData = Data()
        let data = AlexaHttpBodyData.jsonContent()
        guard let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) else { return }
        guard let valueData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObj, options: []) else { return }
        bodyData.append(AlexaHttpBodyData.boundaryBegin)
        bodyData.append(AlexaHttpBodyData.jsonHeaders)
        bodyData.append(AlexaHttpBodyData.jsonContent(data: valueData))
        bodyData.append(AlexaHttpBodyData.boundaryBegin)
        bodyData.append(AlexaHttpBodyData.AudioHeaders)
//        bodyStream = InputStream(data: bodyData)
        let streams = Stream.boundPair(bufferSize: BufferSize, inputStream: bodyStream)
        self.bodyStream = streams.inputStream
        self.outputStream = streams.outputStream
//        RunLoop.current.add(streamingState.sendTimer, forMode: .default)
        outputStream?.delegate = self
        outputStream?.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .default)
        outputStream?.open()
        completionHandler(self.bodyStream)
        outputStream?.write(Array(bodyData), maxLength: bodyData.count)
//        while (true) {
        outputStream?.write(Array(self.audioQueue.dequeue()), maxLength: BufferSize)
        let rndata = "\r\n".data(using: .utf8)
        outputStream?.write(Array(rndata!), maxLength: rndata!.count)
        outputStream?.write(Array(AlexaHttpBodyData.boundaryEnd), maxLength: AlexaHttpBodyData.boundaryEnd.count)

//        }
        stop(error: nil)
    }
```

```
extension Stream {
static func boundPair(bufferSize: Int, inputStream: InputStream?) -> (inputStream: InputStream?, outputStream: OutputStream?) {
        var inStream: InputStream? = inputStream
        var outStream: OutputStream? = nil
        Stream.getBoundStreams(withBufferSize: bufferSize, inputStream: &inStream, outputStream: &outStream)
        return (inStream, outStream)
    }
}
```